# FindResource returns empty Image

Tags: c#, wpf, image, resources, find

In the main window XAML I added resource Image **my_image**.
In the code, find its function FindResource
The function returns a non-null.
But inside the img.Source is empty.
What am I doing wrong?

```
//xaml
    <Window.Resources>
        <Image x:Key="my_image" Source="Properties/images/device1.png"/>
    </Window.Resources>

//c# code

    Image img=this.FindResource("my_image") as Image;
```

UPDATE:
  The problem was solved by pointing assembly type as a resource.
  And also had to create a new instance of the Image **img_new**.
  And give it a Source of what has been obtained from resources.
  Then to normal, we can work with **img_new**.

```
 Image img=this.FindResource("my_image") as Image;
 Image img_new=new Image();
 img_new.Source=img.Source;
```

Comment: to me you are doing nothing wrong. If you put the image inside a Grid, do you see the image?

Comment: when add img in Grid: MyGrid.Children.Add (img);

Get an exception: System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException

Comment: What you see in XAML with <Grid><Image  Source="Properties/images/device1.png"/>
</Grid> ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the Build Action of your device1.png to Resource from Content

Comment: Thank you.
Now img.Source not empty.
I see in the debugger image size and so on.
But when try to add img in Grid: MyGrid.Children.Add (img);

Get an exception: System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException

Comment: I am not able to reproduce your issue. It runs fine for me. Can you share more code?